# Two Three Way Switches w 14/2

Tags: electrical

I have an existing three way switch hooked up already, it works fine. I would like to add another three way switch by connecting another switch to the existing three way switch. Can this be done with 14/2 romex between the two switches?

Comment: A bit of clarification needed. Do you already have two switches controlling the device or only one? Are you trying to add a second switch or a third? (Same question, just 2 ways of saying it.)

Comment: Also, regardless of how you answer @bib, no.  Multi-way switches require an extra conductor.

Comment: @Scivitri In some (odd) configurations, 14/2 between the switches could work if the load was beyond the second switch on the circuit and already had a neutral.

Comment: only one switch is currently controlling the device. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most commonly, in a two switch setup, line power comes to the first switch then goes to the second switch and then to the fixture.

In this setup, you need a three wire cable between the two 3-way switches (we don't count the green or bare ground wire when describing cable). Two of the wires are travelers (alternately serving as the hot line) and the third is the neutral. The hot wire from the line cable in is attached to the common on the first 3-way switch. The neutral from the line in cable is attached to the neutral in the cable to the second switch. At the second switch, the travelers go to the traveler terminals and the hot wire to the fixture cable is attached to the common. The neutral from the traveler cable is attached directly (not through the switch) to the neutral of the fixture cable.

If the second 3-way switch is not between the first switch and the fixture (because there is already a neutral at the fixture), you need at least three wires to the remote switch, two travelers and a return hot line to the fixture. In addition, code now requires a neutral at each switch, so you should have four wire to a remote 3-way (the neutral reserved for devices that may need it in the future).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to clarify your answer? Specifically, the entire first paragraph. A switch between 2 3-ways is a 4-way and not the same configuration; do I misunderstand? There's also no part of a 3-way acting as a neutral; what do you mean? Second paragraph - again, what's the neutral got to do with it; are you speaking about the number of wires? No matter what configuration, a system of 3-ways have 2(3-ways) + m(4-ways) | if 1 3-way exists 2 do...

Comment: I tried to explain more thoroughly. But the question is not about three switches (which do require a 4-way switch). And the same number of cables is needed in a three switch configuration; the 4-way just sits between the travelers.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's said in the comment, sounded like OP's adding between 2 others and wanted to do it with another 3-way. That's what I meant about configuration. Your edit makes it much clearer.