# Connect A 3 way swotch to an existing three way switch

Tags: electrical

I have a 3 way switch (switch A) that controls a device. I have another three way switch (switch B) that is not connected to anything. I would like to connect switch B to switch A so that it can be part of the same circuit, and control the same device. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59398/two-three-way-switches-w-14-2/59404#59404)

Comment: You might want to consider if [this](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59398/two-three-way-switches-w-14-2) question you asked is resolved, as you've depicted with the check, and if not work on improving it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run 4 wires and a ground between the switches,

the neutral which will be capped off due to code reasons

2 travelers which will be connected to the other switch

and a live either from the power source or to the light

and finally the ground to the ground screw.

Comment: with the three wires that are in use, to I just connect to the corresponding connections between the two switches? Meaning, the wires from switch A go to the same location as on switch b? I guess I am asking what the final setup looks like.